# Pyspark Pivot based on column values combinations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 3 columns as shown below

[image]

I would like to Pivot and fill the columns on the  id so that each row contains a
column for each id + column combination where the value is for that id, as shown below

[image]

Note: Zero or Null is shown if the `ID` does not match. For instance `ID2_colA` and `Id2_ColB` get 0 in the first two rows, and `ID1_calA` abd `ID1_ColB` get 0 in row 3
There are more distinct values in `ID` column. Shortened it for the ease of illustration

How can I achieve this in pyspark?

Here is the code for the first dataframe:

```
data = [(("ID1", 3, 5)), (("ID1", 4, 12)), (("ID2", 8, 3))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "colA", "colB"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map column where the values are columns `colA` and  `colB` and the keys concatenation of literal `colA` and  `colB` names with `ID`column. Then, explode the map and pivot the resulting `value` column like this:

```
from itertools import chain
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(
    "ID", "colA", "colB",
    F.explode(
        F.create_map(
            *list(chain(*[[F.concat_ws("_", F.lit(c), F.col("ID")), F.col(c)] for c in ["colA", "colB"]]))
        )
    )
).groupBy("ID", "colA", "colB") \
    .pivot("key").agg(F.first("value")) \
    .fillna(0) \
    .show()

#+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|ID |colA|colB|colA_ID1|colA_ID2|colB_ID1|colB_ID2|
#+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|ID2|8   |3   |0       |8       |0       |3       |
#|ID1|3   |5   |3       |0       |5       |0       |
#|ID1|4   |12  |4       |0       |12      |0       |
#+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```